# Enhanced Class Decompiler in RAD is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiler, ibm-rad

I tried to install the Enhance Class Decompiler on my RAD using the Install software not on the market eclipse. After installation, I was not able to open the jars cause it prompted an error saying that "Editor could not be initialized" see screenshot below.

[image: ERROR]

[image: Decompiler Preference]

[image: File Association]

Hope you can help me. Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

Your Eclipse is too old:

The plugin fails to call the method `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType.getClassFile()` because it does not exist in the Eclipse version you have. The method exists since Eclipse Photon (4.8), which means your Eclipse is even older. You are at least 12 releases and three years behind. Please upgrade.

Comment: @howler As I've checked right now some of the class on the jars is viewable using the decompiler but some jars is not. the classes on the jars that are not viewable are those who does not have the .classpath on the jars. Im not sure if this things matters.

Comment: Only when the missing method is called, you will get the `NoSuchMethodError`. There may be cases where the plugin does not call the method. You would have to look into the source code of the plugin to know when and when not.